# GWT datagrid pagination

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to implement a DataGrid with the pagination features, but it seem to not work. I follow the example implementation of the DataGrid in the GWT Showcase of Features with the SimplePager object but when I add this code to my GWT client class

Class attribute:

```java
DataGrid<List<String>> table = new DataGrid<List<String>>();  
private static List<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
@UiField(provided = true)
SimplePager pager;
```

Method:

```java
SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources, false, 10, true);
pager.setDisplay(table);
```

I don't see the page scrolling arrows and I can't surf my table pages.

Comment: Did you add your pager to your view? What do you see?

Comment: I see the datagrid populated with the data, but i see only 50 rows and i can't see the other row because i can't change the page.

Comment: post your UiBinder template code

Comment: <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder
  xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
  xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
  xmlns:c="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client">

  <g:DockLayoutPanel
    unit="EM">
    <!-- DataGrid. -->
    <g:center>
      <c:DataGrid
        ui:field='dataGrid' />
    </g:center>

Comment: <!-- Pager. -->
    <g:south
      size="3">
      <g:HTMLPanel>
        <table
          style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td
              align='center'>
              <c:SimplePager
                ui:field='pager' />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:south>
  </g:DockLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>

Comment: This is my UiBinder template code, it is the same of GWT Showcase of Features, but i'm a bit confused about the use of the UiBinder template... Where should i put this in the gwt project?

Comment: You didn't use (provided=true) for your DataGrid in your UIBinder. You're essentially creating a new DataGrid that's unattached to the DOM and, then adding the pager to that. Needless to say, it won't do anything.

Your datagrid should be instantiated with the following:

    @UiField(provided=true)
    DataGrid dataGrid;

You'll have to do the initialization work for the Datagrid afterwards, and then attach the pager to this table.